# Is there a way to write the same code without using void functions?

Tags: c++

I'm a C++ beginner, and I was wondering how I can rewrite this code without using `void` functions, and use it all in `main()`.

I know that this program needs to get the longest consecutive substring in a string,
but is there another way to do it without using functions?

## substring in C++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void longestConsecutivecharacter(string letters){
    int finalResult = 1; 
    int letterCounter = 1; 
    char flcrcs; 

    for (int i = 1; i < letters.size(); i++) { 
        if (letters[i] == letters[i + 1]) { 
            ++letterCounter; 
        }
        else { 
            if(letterCounter>finalResult)
                flcrcs=letters[i-1];
            finalResult = max(finalResult, letterCounter);
            letterCounter = 1; 
        }
    } 

    finalResult = max(finalResult, letterCounter); 
    for(int i=0;i<finalResult;i++)
       cout<<flcrcs;  
}; 

int main(){   
    string letters; 
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin>>letters; 
    cout << "The first longest consecutive repeating character substring is: ";
    longestConsecutivecharacter(letters); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's better to use the function versus putting everything in `int main()`

Comment: *"without using void functions"* Change `void longestConsecutivecharacter(string)` into `int longestConsecutivecharacter(string)` and add a final `return 0;` :-)

Comment: There is no benefit in it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it without functions? This method is better and more portable.

If you still want to, you can just take the code and put it in main, like this:

```cpp
int main(){
   string letters; 
   cout << "Enter a string: ";
   cin>>letters; 
   
   int finalResult = 1; 
   int letterCounter = 1; 
   char flcrcs; 

   for (int i = 1; i < letters.size(); i++) { 
     if (letters[i] == letters[i + 1]) { 
       ++letterCounter; 
   }
   else { 
     if(letterCounter>finalResult) {
        flcrcs=letters[i-1];
        finalResult = max(finalResult, letterCounter);
        letterCounter = 1; 
     }
   } 
   finalResult = max(finalResult, letterCounter); 
   for(int i=0;i<finalResult;i++)
   cout << "The first longest consecutive repeating character substring is: ";
   cout<<flcrcs;  
};
```